# Java Scheduled Executor Threads going into Waiting State

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, jedis

So, I am trying to implement a basic async messaging protocol from my Java client to Go server, using two custom threads, with a scheduled thread executor. So, I initiate a single TCP socket from Java client to Go server, and set Read and Write Buffers on both sides.

Writer thread saves a unique ID into Redis server corresponding to each request, and write the request using PrintWriter on TCP socket.

**WriterThread**

```
public class WithdrawRequestWriter extends Thread {

    private static final int START_ACCOUNT_NO = 1;
    private static final int END_ACCOUNT_NO = 2_000;
    private static final int AMOUNT_TO_WITHDRAW = 100;

    private PrintWriter writer;
    private Jedis jedis;

    public WithdrawRequestWriter(PrintWriter writer, Jedis jedis) {
        this.writer = writer;
        this.jedis = jedis;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        for (int accountNo = START_ACCOUNT_NO; accountNo <= END_ACCOUNT_NO; accountNo++) {
            String uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            if (jedis.set(uniqueId, String.valueOf(accountNo), "NX", "EX", 10) != null) {
                writer.write(uniqueId + " " + accountNo + " " + AMOUNT_TO_WITHDRAW + "\n");
                writer.flush();
            } else {
                System.err.println("Setting of UUID in redis failed: " + uniqueId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly, reader thread waits for a response from the server. As soon it receives one, it matches the unique ID in Redis, it mark them as done (success/failure).

**ReaderThread**

```
public class WithdrawRequestReader extends Thread {

    private BufferedReader reader;
    private Jedis jedis;


    public WithdrawRequestReader(BufferedReader reader, Jedis jedis) {
        this.reader = reader;
        this.jedis = jedis;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String response;
        while (true) {
            try {
                if ((response = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] tokenizedResponse = response.split(" ");
                    System.out.println("Response is: " + response);
                    String value = jedis.get(tokenizedResponse[0]);
                    if (value != null) {
                        System.out.println("Request Token: " + tokenizedResponse[0]
                                + " | Status: " + tokenizedResponse[1]
                                + " | Account: " + tokenizedResponse[2]
                                + " | Amount: " + tokenizedResponse[3]
                                + " | Remaining Balance: " + tokenizedResponse[4]
                                + " | ResponeStr: " + tokenizedResponse[5]);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Waiting for response...");
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(3);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Thread**

```
public class TestClient {

    private static final String HOSTNAME = "localhost";
    private static final int PORT = 12410;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket socket = new Socket(HOSTNAME, PORT);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost");

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
//        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        WithdrawRequestReader readerThread = new WithdrawRequestReader(reader, jedis);
        WithdrawRequestWriter writerThread = new WithdrawRequestWriter(writer, jedis);
        scheduledExecutorService.schedule(writerThread, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        scheduledExecutorService.schedule(readerThread, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

When I use a singlePoolThreadExecutor, the tasks are executed sequentially (as expected), and everything goes smooth. But, when I use threadPoolExecutor with two threads, after few read and write, they go into waiting state, indefinitely. I checked from free tools available online if there is some deadlock, but got no help. Below is the thread dump, when they are stuck.

**Thread dump**

```
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (9.0.4+11 mixed mode):

"DestroyJavaVM" #16 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974e06d000 nid=0x2503 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"pool-1-thread-2" #15 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974e06c000 nid=0x6003 waiting on condition [0x000070000c819000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@9.0.4/Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000747cf64b0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@9.0.4/LockSupport.java:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(java.base@9.0.4/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2062)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(java.base@9.0.4/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1119)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(java.base@9.0.4/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:848)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(java.base@9.0.4/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@9.0.4/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@9.0.4/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9.0.4/Thread.java:844)

"pool-1-thread-1" #14 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974e8a9800 nid=0x5e03 waiting on condition [0x000070000c716000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@9.0.4/Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000747cf64b0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@9.0.4/LockSupport.java:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(java.base@9.0.4/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2062)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(java.base@9.0.4/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1119)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(java.base@9.0.4/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:848)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(java.base@9.0.4/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@9.0.4/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@9.0.4/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9.0.4/Thread.java:844)

"Service Thread" #11 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974d827000 nid=0xa003 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Monitor Ctrl-Break" #10 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974e078800 nid=0x5903 runnable [0x000070000c40d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.base@9.0.4/Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(java.base@9.0.4/SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(java.base@9.0.4/SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(java.base@9.0.4/SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(java.base@9.0.4/StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(java.base@9.0.4/StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(java.base@9.0.4/StreamDecoder.java:178)
    - locked <0x0000000747d9ea78> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(java.base@9.0.4/InputStreamReader.java:185)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(java.base@9.0.4/BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(java.base@9.0.4/BufferedReader.java:326)
    - locked <0x0000000747d9ea78> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(java.base@9.0.4/BufferedReader.java:392)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2$1.run(AppMainV2.java:64)

"Common-Cleaner" #9 daemon prio=8 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974e00a000 nid=0xa203 in Object.wait() [0x000070000c30a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@9.0.4/Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000747f37610> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@9.0.4/ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    - waiting to re-lock in wait() <0x0000000747f37610> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at jdk.internal.ref.CleanerImpl.run(java.base@9.0.4/CleanerImpl.java:148)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9.0.4/Thread.java:844)
    at jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(java.base@9.0.4/InnocuousThread.java:122)

"Sweeper thread" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974d81c000 nid=0x5803 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread2" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974d81b000 nid=0xa503 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   No compile task

"C2 CompilerThread1" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974e005000 nid=0xa603 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   No compile task

"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974d81a800 nid=0xa803 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   No compile task

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974e01a800 nid=0x5603 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974d041800 nid=0x4003 in Object.wait() [0x000070000bc75000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@9.0.4/Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000747f0d078> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@9.0.4/ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    - waiting to re-lock in wait() <0x0000000747f0d078> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@9.0.4/ReferenceQueue.java:172)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(java.base@9.0.4/Finalizer.java:216)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974d040800 nid=0x4103 waiting on condition [0x000070000bb72000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.waitForReferencePendingList(java.base@9.0.4/Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.processPendingReferences(java.base@9.0.4/Reference.java:174)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.access$000(java.base@9.0.4/Reference.java:44)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(java.base@9.0.4/Reference.java:138)

"VM Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974e884000 nid=0x4303 runnable 

"GC Thread#0" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974e80d800 nid=0x2a03 runnable 

"GC Thread#1" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974e80e800 nid=0x5303 runnable 

"GC Thread#2" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974d80c800 nid=0x2b03 runnable 

"GC Thread#3" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974d000800 nid=0x2c03 runnable 

"G1 Main Marker" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974e835800 nid=0x4803 runnable 

"G1 Marker#0" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974d80d800 nid=0x4503 runnable 

"G1 Refine#0" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974e80f800 nid=0x4a03 runnable 

"G1 Refine#1" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974d80d000 nid=0x4c03 runnable 

"G1 Refine#2" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974e80f000 nid=0x4e03 runnable 

"G1 Refine#3" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974e806800 nid=0x5003 runnable 

"G1 Young RemSet Sampling" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974e810800 nid=0x2f03 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f974e079800 nid=0x5c03 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 421

Heap
 garbage-first heap   total 131072K, used 10240K [0x0000000740000000, 0x0000000740100400, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 1024K, 11 young (11264K), 0 survivors (0K)
 Metaspace       used 8824K, capacity 9274K, committed 9472K, reserved 1058816K
  class space    used 832K, capacity 927K, committed 1024K, reserved 1048576K
```

I believe the Go server is not an issue, otherwise single thread executor should also stuck, but it is not. Probably, I am having some deadlock, but unable to figure out the exact reason. Can someone please help. If you want anything else, please let me know.

Comment: both your reader's and writer's `run()` methods execute infinite loop. So, when single threaded executor is used, one of your tasks works and another does not. For tasks with infinite loop ExecutorService should not be used, create separate `Thread` for each task.

Comment: Cite from `Jedis` documentation: ...You shouldn't use the same instance from different threads because you'll have strange errors. And sometimes creating lots of Jedis instances is not good enough because it means lots of sockets and connections, which leads to strange errors as well. A single Jedis instance is not threadsafe!...

Comment: Thanks @ZabojCampula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket and stream part of the code seems to be correct. It is correct to use the input and output streams from a socket in parallel because they are independent streams.

The problem is the Jedis component. Jedis is not thread safe. The Jedis documentation says:

> You shouldn't use the same instance from different threads because
>   you'll have strange errors. And sometimes creating lots of Jedis
>   instances is not good enough because it means lots of sockets and
>   connections, which leads to strange errors as well. A single Jedis
>   instance is not threadsafe!...

It is necassary to rewrite the code so that each thread has a private instance of Jedis.

Comment: Yaa, I looked into the documentation. They suggest to use a connection pool, and it is working fine now. :)